# Egyptian Goddess Nakith

Tags: egyptian, goddesses

I am searching for background information on the ancient Egyptian goddess Nakith. Wikipedia says she's a goddess of the underworld. Apart from that I was unable to find more on the web, and Wikipedia references a book which is out of print.

Does anybody know if she was a local goddess and therefore only worshipped in a certain region? If so, where? Additionally, any hints about her exact function in the underworld would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name that you saw was most likely supposed to be transliterated as Nȧkith. The letter ȧ was used for  in one older transliteration scheme of Egyptian, while [most transliteration schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration_of_Ancient_Egyptian#Table_of_transliteration_schemes) transliterate the same letter as ı͗. The name in hieroglyphics is given as ( *nı͗kyṯ*) in the two below sources.

The image and the text around it are given in *The Egyptian Heaven and Hell*, vol. 1, p. [143](https://archive.org/details/theegyptianheave01budgiala/page/143/mode/1up):

[image]

He translates the text as:

> The goddesses who hack at Āpep in the Tuat, who repulse (or, bring to nought) the affairs (or, matters) of the enemies of Rā. Those who are in this picture, and who hold knives, hack asunder Āpep in the Ṭuat each day

The same text and image are given in *The Gods of the Egyptians*, vol. 1, p. [232](https://archive.org/details/cu31924092320500/page/n259/mode/2up), with more or less the same [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVD7k.png) and description (I removed the hieroglyphics from the quote, but they're present in the original):

> Behind the monster serpent stand four goddesses, each armed with a huge knife, whose duty it is to guard the tombs of the four forms of Osiris; the names of the four goddesses are: — Ṭemṭith, Ṭenith, Nȧkith, and Hetemitet. Their duty was to drive away the enemies of Rā, and to hack in pieces with their awful knives the fiend Āpep every day.

See either of the two books above for the context of the surrounding text and image.

[This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331320879_The_Divine_Nik_and_its_Role_in_Egyptian_Theology) gives the meaning of her name (which is transliterated there as Nı͗kṯ) as "punisher," and her function in the texts to punish Apophis (= Āpep). He also connects Nı͗kt to other gods of punishment such as Nı͗k.